# Realtime monitoring, IP cannot be blocked

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, block, readfile

I would like to block IP address from a log file, IPs are collected from access.log file in apache2.
The IPs are correctly collected in file ips.log, but while reading the file to ban collected IPs, the block is not done.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # Store words to avoid an search for
 BADWORDS=( '/etc/passwd' 'file?' 'w00tw00t' 'fckeditor' 'ifconfig' )
 # Get number of elements in the backup_files array
 entries=${#BADWORDS[@]}

 for ((i=0; i<= entries-1; i++))
 do
 setBadWord=${BADWORDS[$i]}

 tail -F /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep --line-buffered "$setBadWord" | while read -r a; do echo "$a" | awk '{ print $1 } ' >> ips.log; done

 done # end for


while IFS= read -r ip; do
iptables -A INPUT -s "$ip" -j DROP
done < ips.log
```

Comment: `tail -F` is invoked for the first `$setBadWord` but won't complete until it is killed.

Comment: @jhnc: So how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has many issues:

- it runs a new copy of `awk` for every line selected (`awk` is not needed at all);
- it tries to run the first loop multiple times (once for every element of `"$BADWORDS"`)
- the first loop never finishes (because of `tail -F`) and so the `iptables` loop never starts
- the `iptables` command appends a new rule even if the IP has been seen before
- it is simpler to write `i<entries` rather than `i<=entries-1`, and even simpler to just use `for setBadword in "${BADWORDS[@]}"; do ...`

---

If you really want to permanently loop reading the logfile, with GNU utilities you can do something like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

log=/var/log/apache2/access.log
words=/my/list/of/badwords/one/per/line
banned=/my/list/of/already/banned/ips

tail -F "$log" |\
grep --line-buffered -Ff "$words" |\
while read ip junk; do
    grep -qxF $ip "$banned" || (
        iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j DROP
        echo $ip >> "$banned"
    )
done

# we never get here because "tail -F" never finishes
```

To just process the logfile once and then finish, you can feed `grep` from `"$log"` directly:

```
grep --line-buffered -Ff "$words" "$log" | ...
```

but it is probably less error-prone to just use [`fail2ban`](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters) which is explicitly designed for this sort of task.

Comment: I am not familiar with fal2ban, I have basic rules ONLY, if you can help with a link that have more deep rules I will appreciate it. Can I place this file in `/etc/init.d/` directory so it will run automatically on boot, OR I will set a cron only